# How to show the hidden contents under "View More" when using Selenium - Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'XXXX\chromedriver.exe')
FB_bloomberg_URL = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/FB:US'
driver.get(FB_bloomberg_URL)

board_members = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* [@id="root"]/div/div/section[3]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')[0]
board=board_members.text
board.split('\n')
```

[image]

I wrote the coding above to **scrape** the board information from Bloomberg for FaceBook. But I have trouble to extract all board members because others are hidden behind the "View More". How can I extract all names?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can expand view if it's come and the extract further content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do whole thing with `requests` and grab the appropriate cookie to pass to API from prior `GET`. The API can be found in the network tab when clicking the `view more` link and inspecting the web traffic.

[image]

---

```
import requests

headers = {
    'dnt': '1',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'referer': 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/FB:US',
    'authority': 'www.bloomberg.com',
    'cookie':''
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/FB:US')
    headers['cookie'] = s.cookies.get_dict()['_pxhd']
    r = s.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/peopleForCompany/11092218', headers = headers).json()
    board_members = [item['name'] for item in r['boardMembers']]
    print(board_members)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I applied the code but I received the error:"NameError: name 's' is not defined". What is that "s"?

Comment: Hi, Was due to my changing the code reverted to original.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have trouble finding the 'https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/peopleForCompany/11092218'. How can I find this link?

Comment: load the original url. Then press F12 to open dev tools > go to Network tab > Press F5 to refresh page > filter on XHR traffic > use Ctrl + F on network traffic to pull up search box and search for /api/ or for a value present on the page

Comment: hmm. I still didn't find the "/peopleForCompany/11092218"

Comment: oops... remember to click on the view more

Comment: Cool! I missed clicking on the view more. Thanks again for your help.